# Flutter dependency fetching failed (pub get failed)

Tags: flutter, dart

About to run [this project](https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_twitter_clone)

and upon running a command `flutter pub get` I got this error:

```
maciej@ola:~/workdir/flutter/flutter_twitter_clone$ flutter pub get
Because flutter_twitter_clone depends on flutter_link_preview ^1.5.6 which depends on http ^0.12.1, http ^0.12.1 is required.
So, because flutter_twitter_clone depends on http ^0.13.3, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_twitter_clone...                   
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_twitter_clone depends on http ^0.13.3, version solving failed.)
```

This issue has already been raised in [Github](https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_twitter_clone/issues/216) but not resolved yet.

how can I solve it?

Comment: did you try without version  just like `http:`

Answer (score 1):

You are having a dependency version issue, there are several ways to workaround this.

1. Force a specific version for all dependants on package `http`

```dart
dependency_overrides: http: ^0.13.3
```

2. Upgrade or downgrade the conflicting package(version) in your `pubspec.yaml`
3. Fork the conflicting package and update its dependencies, and use your fork. Ideally you'll submit a PR to the package author.

In your particular case the latest version of this package is the one you have, and is using an old `http` version. So you can't do #2

So the easiest solution is #1.